# Minimum notation of modified set elements analog to Sum notation

Tags: notation

I'm currently trying to simplify a calculation that takes the minimum of all elements in a set. However the elements should not be taken as they are but be modifiable:

$$
S = \{{A}, {B}, {C}\}\\
min(({f}_{A} \cdot {m}_{A}), ({f}_{B} \cdot {m}_{B}), ({f}_{C} \cdot {m}_{C}))
$$

Is there any way to write this shorter for all elements, if it was a sum not a minimum it would be some like this:

$$
\sum\limits_{x \in S}^x {f}_{x} \cdot {m}_{x} 
$$

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to write this would be $$\min_{x\in S}\{f_x\cdot m_x\}$$ Or sometimes with $()$ instead of $\{\}$.

Comment: Sometimes also: $$\min\{f_x\cdot m_x\mid x\in S\}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I'll go with the sub-notation as it reminds me of the sum notation.